# How to store the results of one function into a class?

Tags: python, class, oop

So I have created two classes. The first (myModel) has a function which can calculate income with the "predictFinalIncome" function. I simplified it for the purpose of SO.

```
class myModel:
  """
  The earning growth model for individuals in the utopia 
  """
  def __init__(self, bias) :
    """
    :param bias: we will use this potential bias to explore different scenarios to the functions of gender and ethnicity

    :param b_0: the intercept of the model.\ 

    :param b_age: age at world creation

    :param b_education: similar. 

    :param b_gender: similar

    :param b_marital: marital status

    :param b_ethnic: similar

    :param b_industry: similar

    :param b_income: similar.
    """

    self.bias = bias # bias is a dictionary with info to set bias on the gender function and the ethnic function

  def predictFinalIncome( self, n, person ): 
    for i in range(n):
      n_income = n_income* i
    return n_income
```

So this class takes in a "Person" dict like:

```
utopModel = myModel( { "gender": False, "ethnic": False } ) 
months = 12
plato = { "age": 58, "education": 20, "gender": 1, "marital": 0, "ethnic": 2, "industry": 7, "income": 100000 }
utopModel.predictFinalIncome(months,plato)
```

So my goal is to create a class (Person) that can store the predictFinalIncome() of a given Person each time that function is called, thus removing the prior one. This is so I can keep track of a person and store their predicted incomes as I call the function.

I would like to store this in the Person as income.

```
class Person:
  """
  The attributes of a Person to build a person up, having their information in one place as it changes.
  """
  def __init__(self, bias) :
    """
    :param age: person's age

    :param education: person's years of education 

    :param gender: male or female

    :param marital: marital status

    :param ethnic: ethnicity

    :param industry: what sector of work

    :param income: salary
    """
  def age00(self, age):
    return age

  def age(self, age):
    return 

  def income00(self, income):
    return income

  def income(self, n, income):
    return 

  def __getitem__(self, item):
    return self.__dict__[item]
```

Comment: That's a lot of code! You may have more luck boiling this down to a short example.

Comment: @tdelaney took your advice! Could use the help

Comment: why you don't write `predictFinalIncome` inside your `person` class and keep the value in a property of the class?

Comment: @JohnnyThomas Hey guy, you want to update the income of specific person when you call `predictFinalIncome()` ? I'm right ?

Comment: @NimaNr they have to be seperate.

Comment: @leminhnguyenHUST yes that's correct; I also need to update their age, which is indicated by the amount of months past /12.

Comment: @JohnnyThomas oke, I'll post the solution

Comment: number of months passed, indicated by n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there're 2 solutions here:

1. You write `predictFinalIncome` inside `Person`. When you call `predictFinalIncome` method you'll save the income value as property of the `Person` class
2. you pass `Person` instance as parameter of the `predictFinalIncome` method. And after calculating income you use that instance to save. See below

```
def predictFinalIncome( self, n, specificPerson: Person ): 
    for i in range(n):
      n_income = n_income* i

    # new lines
    specificPerson.income += n_income #income updated
    specificPerson.age = ((specificPerson.age*12) + n)/12 # age updated
```

And when you call `predictFinalIncome` outside:

```
utopModel = myModel( { "gender": False, "ethnic": False } ) 
months = 12
specificPerson = Person(..something here..)
utopModel.predictFinalIncome(months,specificPerson)
```

Now your `specificPerson` instance updates the income automatically when you call `predictFinalIncome` method

Answer (score 0):

so NimaNr's solution (in your comments) is probably the simplest solution.

If you keep predictFinalIncome() in your myModel class, you're going to want to make a **setter** function for your Person's income variable. It'd look like this:

```
def setIncome(self, x):
    self.Income = x
```

What you'd want to do in your *predictFinalIncome* method is call the setter we just made above with the n_income value you've got.